# javascript setInterval() inside jQuery dialog not stopping on destroy or remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery dialog that appears and loads an external page. In that page i am running a `setInterval()` function that queries my server continuously every 1 second (AJAX). The problem is that when i close the dialog, the setInterval doesn't stop running.

here is the code for the dialog:

```
var theUrl = 'someUrl';

var popUp = document.createElement('div');

$(popUp).dialog({
        width: 400,
        height: 270,
        title: "Some Title",
        autoOpen: true,
        resizable:false,
        close: function(ev, ui) {
                    $(this).dialog('destroy');
               },
        modal: true,
        open: function() { 
                    $(this).load(theUrl);
              }
});
```

I tried calling `$(this).dialog('destroy')` and `$(this).remove()` and `document.body.removeChild(popUp)` on close. nothing worked. is there anyway to 'unload' the loaded page?

Comment: setInterval has nothing to do with the DOM or jQuery. It needs to be cleared separately, maybe in effect of a DOM event like "close".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setInterval` returns a handler that you can pass to `clearInterval` to stop the function from running.  Here's a basic example of how it works.

```
var handler = setInterval(function() {}, 2000);
clearInterval(handler);
```

For your example you'd want to call `clearInterval` in the `close` method of the `ui.dialog`.

Docs:

`setInterval` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval

`clearInterval` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearInterval

**Edit**

You will not be able to call `clearInterval` without the stored handler from `setInterval`, therefore if the call to `setInterval` is in another script the only way you're going to capture the handler is to override `window.setInterval` itself.

```
$(function() {
    var originalSetInterval = window.setInterval;
    var handlers = [];

    window.setInterval = function() {
        handlers.push(arguments[0]);
        originalSetInterval(arguments);
    };

    $('whatever').dialog({
        close: function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < handlers.length; i++) {
                clearInterval(handlers[i]);
            }
            handlers = [];
        }
    });
});
```

Note that the code to override `window.setInterval` must come before including the `<script>` tag to bring in the external file.  Also this approach will clear all interval functions whenever `clearInterval` is called, therefore this is not ideal, but it's the only way you're going to accomplish this.